# Hide once & for all the only file that handles logins - wp-login.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've tried to solve this issue for months now, every solution I've found is not working properly or is just easy to pass.

**Rules:**

- Users can login, register, use lost password etc on front-end - got that covered!
- Every direct access to wp-admin, admin, wp-login, login should show 404 or redirect to home

**What I've tried & failed (maybe did something wrong) or think of trying:**

- Copy-paste & rename wp-login.php, then use [wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url) and [wp_login_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) to make all those actions thro this file - not sure if other WP functionalities need "wp-login.php" to work properly
- Make a function to functions.php that checks if "secret string" is added to the end of URL, redirect others or show 404
- Just ordinary redirect
- Tried different plugins
- Read & tried atleast 50 .htaccess codes found online (not kidding)

**Problems I've had:**

- Ordinary redirection: unable to login or logout
- How all plugins have worked: only hides wp-login.php, you can still use login, admin & wp-admin
- .htaccess outcomes so far: added "link" only redirects to wp-login.php but by all means doesn't hide it, change it or replace wp-login with the new "link" in URL

---

**What almost worked:**

```
//Don't Let Users To Login Page
function example_simple_query_string_protection_for_login_page() {

   //Secret string
   $QS = '?secret=1';

   $theRequest = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . 'wp-login.php' . '?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  if ( site_url('/wp-login.php').$QS == $theRequest ) {
      //Shows WP login page
  } 

  else {
      //Redirects to home page
      header( 'Location: https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' );

      //Shows 404 - Doesn't work as expected!!
      //include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
  }
}

 add_action('login_head', 'example_simple_query_string_protection_for_login_page');
```

**Problems with it:**

- Didn't find any good online solution how to force "real" 404!
- User doesn't get redirected if he/she goes to wp-admin or admin - instead he/she gets 403 Forbidden errror and ugly WP restricted access screen!

My code that handles this but doesn't work for some reason:

```
//Disable wp-admin For Non-Admins If Not Running AJAX Or Updating User Data
function disable_wp_admin_for_non_admins() {
  if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') &&  $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' && !ajax_add_remove_favorites() && !ajax_update_user_profile_function() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'disable_wp_admin_for_non_admins');
```

---

### **QUESTIONS:** need only 1 that works!

- Would copy-paste-rename wp-login theoretically work Or does other functions need that name?
- Once and for all, can you achieve what I want with .htaccess?
- How to get my code to work? (show 404 and don't show 403 to logged in users)
- Is there any other solution that would work but Im not aware of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/disable-or-redirect-wp-login-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to throw a 404 error on another project recently. Not sure of the best filter/action to wrap this in, but I used `parse_request`.

```
add_action('parse_request', 'prevent_wp_login_access');

function prevent_wp_login_access() 
{
    global $wp_query;

    //check to see if the page is wp-login.php
    //if so
    //force 404
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    require TEMPLATEPATH.'/404.php';
    exit;
}
```

You could also try wrapping it in the `init` action, and throwing your own `header()` if the `$wp_query` object is not available yet.

Just a thought.

Comment: I finally see light at the end of the tunnel. I get 404 with every URL I wanted. There is only 1 problem now - login works but **registering also gives 404 if I hit submit button..** `wp-login.php?action=register` Any idea what to do with it?

Comment: Also there's always 2 404 errors in consol for some reason & there's sometimes even 3 GETs with wp-login.php with 404 in inspector network tab, is that normal?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting multiple 404s. Could have something to do with the request being routed to multiple pages throwing 404s?

Comment: You are using the built-in WP registration mechanism, but controlling the redirect? Is that correct? You could check for the page and action within your filter and allow if it exists, throw 404 if not...

Comment: That 404 subject is very weird because I get it with every 404. It always GETs the page for 2-3 times. About registering.. That was one of my original question actually I didn't find answer for. Is there a way to login/register without using wp-login directly?

Comment: `wp_signon()` will allow you to log a user in. `wp_insert_user()` will allow you to register/create a new user. Use these in your own methods/pages to create the desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you! If it really passes wp-login, I'll check it out.

Comment: You can redirect your users away from wp-login and recreate the desired functionality with these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following for preventing access to wp-login.php. It accounts for logouts as well, so shouldn't give you an issues. Not sure if it will play nicely with other aspects of WP.

```
add_action('init', 'prevent_wp_login_access');

function prevent_wp_login_access() 
{
    global $pagenow;

    if( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'logout' )
        return;

    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') );
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. My current code basically does the same in the end, please read "Problems with it:" section. Maybe you have any suggestions? Same problems apply to this solution.

Comment: Well would you like a redirect? Or a 404? You can't have both. This way implements a redirect. If you want to throw a 404 instead, that is possible using a similar approach.

Comment: I would solve the issues with wp-admin with a separate filter/action

Comment: Haha, I know. I would prefer to use 404. Do you know any good solution to 403 problem? All that I've found end up with same result as my code. (Check the code below "problems' list").

Comment: I added another answer that would throw a 404. You could modify it for the wp-admin directories as well

Comment: Thank you! I'll let you know how it goes.